# Configure SSSD (sudo and dyndns_update) with realmd

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, sssd

I'm trying to join a Ubuntu 16.04 to a Windows domain (active directory) using realmd + sssd. Basically I was following [this post](https://www.mylesgray.com/infrastructure/utilising-kerberosad-auth-ubuntu-14-04-realmd/) which worked pretty well and I was able to join my server and could successfully authenticate as AD user. However there are two pieces missing in the integration:

1. Register server's hostname in DNS
2. Use [sssd-sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-sudo) for user authorization

**Register server's hostname in DNS**

As mentioned I successfully join the AD by using 
`realm join --user=dpr MYDOMAIN.INT --install=/`:

```
root@ip-172-28-5-174 ~ # realm list
mydomain.int
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: MYDOMAIN.INT
  domain-name: mydomain.int
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@mydomain.int
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

However, dispite the successful join, my server is not known to the other machines in the domain using its hostname `ip-172-28-5-174.mydomain.int`. I found [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/sssd-ad-options.html#sssd-dyndns) that mentions a `dyndns_update` setting in the sssd.conf file.

As I'm using realm. The sssd configuration is generated automatically by issuing the join command. The generated config file looks like this:

```
[sssd]
domains = mydomain.int
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/mydomain.int]
ad_domain = mydomain.int
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.INT
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
```

That is I somehow need to add `dyndns_update = True` to this generated file. But how?

**Use sssd-sudo for user authorization**

Additionally I want to make sssd to read my sudo configuration from AD. I think this can be achieved using [sssd-sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-sudo) but this needs to be enabled/configured in the sssd.conf file as well by adding `sudo` to the sssd services and use `sudo_provider = ldap` for my domain. Again I'm not able to figure out how to do this with realm.

Basically I want my generated config file to look like this:

```
[sssd]
domains = mydomain.int
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo

[domain/mydomain.int]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
sudo_provider = ldap
ad_domain = mydomain.int
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.INT
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you clarify reading your `sudo` configuration from AD, please. The access groups? Or the specifications of programs, aliases, etc.? Groups "just happen". The remainder of the specifications are (much) harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there doesn't seem to be an option to add custom configuration parameters to the sssd.conf file generated by realmd.

I had to adjust the generated config to contain my needed settings **after** joining the domain with `realm join` and restart sssd (`service restart sssd`) for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

If you want Active Directory to manage `sudoers`, you have to load a specialized schema into AD and then create your rules using a tool like ADSI Edit.  [This walkthrough](http://jhrozek.livejournal.com/3860.html) worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  The highlights are:

- Import `schema.ActiveDirectory`
- Create rules following the [sudoers-ldap manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html)
- Update `etc/nsswitch.conf` to include `sss` among the entries on the `sudoers =` line
- Update `etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to include:

  - `sudo` among the entries on the `services =` line
  - an empty `[sudo]` section (no configs are required, but [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-ldap-sudo.html) asserts that this triggers the proper configuration of sudo support)
  - a line like `sudo_provider = ad` (sssd docs on [pagure.org](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd-test2/HOWTO_Troubleshoot_SUDO.html) claim sudo provider is enabled by default for ldap, ad and ipa so this may be optional)

When I repeat this process for 16.04 (i.e. same AD rules as 14.04), I'm actually having other issues.  Apparently, this is [not uncommon](https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2016-August/msg00447.html).  It's possible that there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1665322) in the version of sudo included in 16.04.

- In principle, manually upgrading to [the latest](https://www.sudo.ws/download.html) should resolve this issue.
- The regular `sudo` package (not `sudo-ldap`) is the right package if you want SSSD (and not `sudo`) to manage the ldap connection.  Specifically, installing `sudo-ldap` produced no logs in `sssd_sudo.log` while the regular `sudo` package did.
- While `sssd_sudo` is now showing `Returning 2 rules for [<user>@<domain>]`, `sudo -l` is still responding with `Sorry, user <user>@<domain> may not run sudo on <host>` so there may be other issues needing resolved.

My situation may not be typical, however, as I'm having additional issues that don't appear to be common.  For example, I had issues running `realm join` that were resolved using workarounds from [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/q/829996/346101).

If you found your way here due to realmd/sssd/sudo issues in 16.04, here are some other reported problems that may be helpful (not necessarily directly related to the OP's issue):

- [IPA host netgroup issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1607666) (more info on the [free-ipa users list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2016-August/msg00503.html))
- There's a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/realmd/+bug/1333694) with realmd dependency resolution.  As mentioned in the discussion, installing packagekit resolves for many (including us).  There may be a [separate issue](http://www.wolffhaven45.com/blog/linux/join_ubuntu_workstation_windows_domain/#6) with the version in 16.04.

We're evaluating 16.04 for upgrade so we may put this on the back burner, but hopefully our legwork helps others.