# Get sudoers through LDAP (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12)

Tags: linux, sudo, ldap, sssd, nsswitch

I have a problem with my LDAP configuration on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12.

As many of you know, the ldap.conf file has been replaced with sssd.conf and a couple of other conf files like nsswitch.conf.

I want to have authentication through LDAP, picking users from a specific OU. I also need to get the definition for sudoers through LDAP.
I have never worked with sssd before.

My current NSS configuration looks as follows:

```
passwd: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
group:  files ldap

hosts:  files dns
networks:       files

services:       files
protocols:      files
rpc:    files
ethers: files
netmasks:       files
netgroup:       files nis
publickey:      files

bootparams:     files
automount:      files nis
aliases:        files
passwd_compat:  files
group_compat:   files
sudoers:        ldap files [I added this line]
```

And here is my sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = *****
sbus_timeout = 30

[nss]
filter_users = root
filter_groups = root
reconnection_retries = 3
entry_cache_timeout = 300
entry_cache_nowait_percentage = 75

[pam]

[domain/GuH]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_user_object_class = posixAccount
debug_level = 20
#access_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldap://******.de
ldap_search_base = o=***
create_homedir = truei
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/sssd/certs/*******.pem
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/sssd/certs
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=********,o=guh
ldap_default_authtok_type = *******
ldap_default_authtok = *********
ldap_user_member_of = *********
ldap_group_name = cn=*******,ou=*******,ou=******,o=******
```

Just assume the * are put in correctly.

Also, is there anything to do in a PAM config file? I have not seen anyone address it yet.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-ldap-sudo.html <- it's a redhat doc, but should apply to any distro

Comment: unfortunatly it only works until some redhead specific points come into play like "authconfig"

Comment: Eh? `authconfig` is mentioned nowhere on the page.

Comment: But on other pages (if you open the dropdown menu at the bottom) that are required for my setup to function.

Comment: Not as it pertains to this question. All the sudo information is on that page.

Comment: It needs mre thn that to have the auth work trough ldap. Thats why i posted my config files. I Also asked about pam, wich the link does not adress at all. However I figured a few of those things out so its okay

Answer (score 0):

[This walkthrough](http://jhrozek.livejournal.com/3860.html) worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  Also, the [Redhat page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-ldap-sudo.html) referenced in the comments doesn't appear to reference `authconfig` anymore.   The highlights are:

- If your LDAP doesn't include one, import a sudoers scheme (e.g. `schema.ActiveDirectory` is required by Active Directory)
- Create rules following the [sudoers-ldap manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html) (in Active Directory, using a tool like ADSI Edit)
- Update `etc/nsswitch.conf` to include `sss` among the `sudoers =`
- Update `etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to include:

  - `sudo` among the `services =`
  - a `sudo_provider =` line (in my case `ad` for Active Directory, but possibly `ldap`)
  - an empty `[sudo]` section (no configs are required, but Redhat asserts that this triggers the proper configuration of sudo support)

A lot of folks have run into issues due to bugs in various parts of the stack so see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/360294/84617) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/372314/84617) if you have any issues.  FWIW [these instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System-Level_Authentication_Guide/troubleshooting-sudo.html) got me enough debug information to confirm that the rules were flowing all the way to sudo, specifically:

- Add the following lines to /etc/sudo.conf:

  ```
  Debug sudo /var/log/sudo_debug.log all@debug
  Debug sudoers.so /var/log/sudo_debug.log all@debug
  ```
- Run the sudo command as the user you want to debug