# LDAP Sudoers w/ AD & SSSD (returns only primary group)

Tags: sudo, active-directory, sssd

I'm having issues getting LDAP sudoers rules to work.  My environment is:

- Active Directory on Windows Server 2012 R2
- Ubuntu 16.04.2
- SSSD 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.5
- sudo 1.8.20-3 (latest as of the posting, tried both LDAP and non-LDAP versions)

I followed [these instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System-Level_Authentication_Guide/troubleshooting-sudo.html) to create a sudo_debug.log (sanitized):

```
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] Received 2 rule(s)
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] -> sudo_sss_filter_result @ ./sssd.c:225
...
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] sssd/ldap sudoHost 'ALL' ... MATCH!
...
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] val[0]=%linuxadmins
...
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] sudo_get_grlist: looking up group names for user@domain.com
...
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] sudo_getgrgid: gid 1157000513 [] -> group domain users@domain.com [] (cache hit)
...
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] user_in_group: user user@domain.com NOT in group linuxadmins
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] <- user_in_group @ ./pwutil.c:1031 := false
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] user user@domain.com matches group linuxadmins: false @ usergr_matches() ./match.c:969
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] <- usergr_matches @ ./match.c:970 := false
Jun 19 14:53:28 sudo[60452] sssd/ldap sudoUser '%linuxadmins' ... not (user@domain.com)
...
```

From this log, you can see that:

- the sudoers rules are getting from AD to sudo (2 rules, the one displayed matching an AD entry)
- the match fails on the `linuxadmins` group

However, the user is in the `linuxadmins` group (sanitized, but "user" matches):

```
$ getent group linuxadmins
linuxadmins@domain.com:*:1157001133:user@domain.com,otheruser@domain.com
```

The only odd thing about this log is that it `sudo_get_grlist` appears to return only the user's Primary Group `domain users@domain.com`.  This would explain the lack of a match.

Has anyone seen this before?  Any idea if the list of groups is resolved inside sudo (that I should continue to wait on my question to `sudo-users`) or somewhere else like SSSD (that I should find their list)?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the lack of primary groups is probably the issue. The fact that `getent group` works is irrelevant, `sudo` uses the initgroups output which is more or less what you get when you call `id`.

And you're also right that sssd-users is the best one: https://lists.fedorahosted.org/admin/lists/sssd-users.lists.fedorahosted.org/

We even fixed our troubleshooting guide not so long ago at https://pagure.io/docs/SSSD/sssd/, the direct link is https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/troubleshooting.html

Comment: I actually contacted `sudo-users` but will also follow up on `sssd-users` if I get blocked there.  The `id` command actually shows all of the right groups as well, but thanks for confirming the diagnostic step.

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7, I was having the same issue of id only showing primary groups, e.g.:

```
id DOMAIN\\administrator

uid=485400500(administrator) gid=485400513(domain users) groups=485400513(domain users)
```

I was reading this reference [(link)](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3023951) and editing my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, and realized I was missing a few recommended configuration options.  Before, I had only:

```
[domain/AD.DOMAIN]
id_provider = ad
```

so I added the other flags mentioned by the reference just underneath it:

```
auth_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
```

Unfortunately I don't know which one of them is responsible for the improvement, but if I had to guess it would be `auth_provider = ad`. Now `id` has this result:

```
id DOMAIN\\administrator

uid=485400500(administrator) gid=485400513(domain users) 
groups=485400513(domain users),485400518(schema admins),485400519(enterprise 
admins),485400512(domain admins),485403117(sudoers),485400520(group policy 
creator owners),485400572(denied rodc password replication 
group),485401624(esx admins),485401679(wseremotewebaccessusers), 
485401680(wseallowshareaccess),485401681(wseallowcomputeraccess),
485401682(wseallowmediaaccess),485401683(wseallowadd inaccess),485401684(wseallowdashboardaccess),
485401685(wseallowhomepagelinks),45401686(wsealertadministrators),
485401687(wseremoteaccessusers),485403103(ipamad mins)
```

Comment: My issue was not with `id` (which shows the right groups) but a deeper issue inside sudoers.  In your case, `auth_provider` *should* default to the value of `id_provider` and `chpass_provider` should default to `auth_provider` (as stated in the relevant sections of [the man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sssd.conf/)).  `access_provider`, by contrast, should default to `permit` (same page).  It's possible that you worked around a bug but, in general, `id_provider` should be sufficient.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info!  Network authorization on Linux is still somewhat mysterious to me, it's taken me a long time to even get as far as I have.  I'm going to leave it up just in case it helps someone else.